# paypal error in cart

Tags: opencart

I'm using OC1.5.1 and I'm trying to integrate PayPal.

The problem is I get an error in the checkout:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function encrypt() on a non-object in /var/www/example.com/httpdocs/catalog/controller/payment/pp_standard.php on line 94`

Is there any way past this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you've not go the `/system/library/encryption.php` file uploaded. Double check that the file isn't empty

EDIT: Or the line

```
$registry->set('encryption', new Encryption($config->get('config_encryption')));
```

could be missing. Check it's set in the `index.php` file